# Does liquibase not support "where not exists" clause with postgres as database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

"Where not exists" clause is not recognized by liquibase when inserting a row  on a postgres database

```sql
insert into table (col1, col2) 
values (val1, val2)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from table where col1 = val1)/
```

Error message:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

It works fine without liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

No, syntax is wrong. Consider using :

```
insert into "table" (col1, col2) 
select val1, val2 
  from table0
 where not exists ( select 1 from "table" where col1 = val1 )
```

where `table0` is the source and `"table"` is the target.

Comment: or `select val1, val2 where not exists ...`

Comment: so nice @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't know.